# OSMdroid point of interest

Tags: osmdroid, point-of-interest

Hy I am new to osmdroid and i have code to point my location, now I am trying to mark poi(point of interest ect. cinema, bus station...) on map but I don't know how to do it. Is there anyone who had done it or knows some good tutorial where is explained how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

OsmBonusPack should cover your need.